# How to convert complex xml to csv using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, converters

i need to convert xml into csv. i tried xmlutils library i couldn't get expected fields. actually my xml doesn't have common tags in the xml tree.
xml sample:

```
<service.className>
    <Id>3001</Id>
    <sId>12.*</sId>
    <qId>1</qId>
    <timeR>123</timeR>
    <pId>1/1/7</pId>
    <sMode/>
    <highipvalue>1</highipvalue>
    <highipvalue2>1</highipvalue2>
    <highipvalue3>1</highipvalue3>
</service.className>
<service.className>
    <Id>3001</Id>
    <sId>12.*</sId>
    <policy>2</policy>
    <timeR>123</timeR>
    <pId>1/1/7</pId>
    <sMode>mode1</sMode>
    <medipvalue>1</medipvalue>
    <medipvalue2>1</medipvalue2>
    <medipvalue3>1</medipvalue3>
</service.className>
<service.className>
    <Id>3001</Id>
    <sId>12.*</sId>
    <policy>3</policy>
    <timeR>123</timeR>
    <pId>1/1/7</pId>
    <sMode>mode2</sMode>
    <lowipvalue>1</lowipvalue>
    <lowipvalue2>1</lowipvalue2>
    <lowipvalue3>1</lowipvalue3>
</service.className>
```

and so on repeating.......

the expected csv output:

```
Id  sId qid policyid    timeR   pId sMode   highipvalue highipvalue2    highipvalue3    medipvalue  medipvalue2 medipvalue3 lowipvalue  lowipvalue2 lowipvalue3
3001    12.*    1   0   123 1/01/2007   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3001    12.*    0   2   123 1/01/2007   mode1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0
3001    12.*    0   3   123 1/01/2007   mode2   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
```

but now i'm getting fields in csv only first element tree of xml like below

```
Id  sId qid policyid    timeR   pId sMode   highipvalue highipvalue2    highipvalue3
3001    12.*    1   0   123 1/01/2007       1   1   1
3001    12.*    0   2   123 1/01/2007   mode1   1   1   1
3001    12.*    0   3   123 1/01/2007   mode2   1   1   1
```

code i tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from xmlutils.xml2csv import xml2csv
out_csv_path=csv path
in_xml_path=xml path
converter = xml2csv(in_xml_path, out_csv_path, encoding="utf-8")
converter.convert(tag="className",buffer_size=1000,quotes=False)
```

any help much appreciated.

Advance Thanks,
Mani

Comment: Show us what you have tried!

Comment: i tried below function for conversion.
converter = xml2csv(in_xml_path, out_csv_path, encoding="utf-8")
                converter.convert(tag=XML_NAMESPACE_STRING +className,
                                  buffer_size=1000,
                                  quotes=False)

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question. It is not readable in the comments.

Comment: *i couldn't get expected fields*: You have **missing tags**, therefore you must **add** the missing **tags**.

Comment: i couldn't get what you refereeing as tags. pls tell me where to add tags?

Comment: i couldn't get what you refereeing as tags. pls tell me where to add tags?

converter.convert(tag="className",buffer_size=1000,quotes=False)
here should i pass tag as list of fields fields as header ?

Comment: `xmlutils` does **not** support to **add** tags. Your `XML` looks that all `<service.className>` refer to the same `<Id>3001</Id>`. Therefore, you have first to aggreate all `<Id>3001</Id>` to flatten your XML.

Comment: is it any other python library available for this conversion?